# Flash not working on phonegap 2.7 android 4.x

Tags: android, flash, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm integrating a page inside Phonegap2.7 which uses a flash player.

To enable Flash in phonegap I used

```
super.init();
super.appView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
```

So everything worked perfectly on Android 2.3 but failed on 4.x devices.

So I tried the followings as per some questions in SO

```
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
WebView webView= new WebView(this);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
```

Not working no error.

And

```
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState;

WebSettings settings = appView.getSettings(); 
settings.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
```

Same result. Run but no error show and no content in player.External pages are working fully, I checked them in pc browser.

in Log CAT this massages are shown but not as error.

> 02-14 12:19:22.435: D/WebCore/FrameLoaderClientAndroid(10204):
>   FrameLoaderClientAndroid::frameLoaderDestroyed() this=0x11001e8 02-14
>   12:19:22.435: D/WebCore/FrameLoaderClientAndroid(10204):
>   FrameLoaderClientAndroid::~FrameLoaderClientAndroid() this=0x11001e8

And so on. This massages don't show on my android 2.3 and runs perfectly as I wanted. What I'm missing? What to do to run the pages with flash working on android 4.x??